# Select all faces parallel to ground

Tags: scripting, selection-tools, select

Is there a way to select all faces in my mesh that have normals that point upwards, with a range of how much they need to be pointing upwards to be selected?
I have a mesh of a house, and I want to add a solar panel material to all the faces that point upwards but the mesh just has too many faces to do it manually. It also has an inside that I do not want to be selected. I am not sure whether this  will involve scripting (I know absolutely nothing about scripting by the way)
Preferably, my selection would look something like this:
[image]
Thanks in advance for any advice anyone gives me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use <kbd>c</kbd> for circle select and pick the top parts of the globes then either grow selection or use select similar.

Select similar which is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> can be used to find faces with similar angles/direction which should be your best bet. Then just grow your selection using 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>
More ways to select can be found here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/selecting.html

Comment: yes shift G > Normals then play with the Threshold of the Operator box, or ctrl +, seems to be the solution

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly, I will have to deselect a few things like the floor inside and window ledges, but that will be nothing compared to the amount of work that it would be to select everything manually.